# Creating a manual link to Pentaho report

Tags: reporting-services, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I'm using Pentaho report designer 3.9.4.  I have an element "project_name" in my main report with several rows. I need to link the project_name element to the appropriate Pentaho report for every generated row.  The project_name element should be a hyperlink to a project report having a naming convention based on the contents of the project_name element and the parameters the main report passes in.  The name of the linked report is determined by the project name element.  As an example below is the column Project_Name as it is displayed on the main Pentaho report with an example of the output.  The main report is generated by a PDI process that brings in two parameters that need to be concatenated to the generic url for every combination.

Parameters passed into the main report:
**department_name**
**staff_member**

The generic url for example is http://www.somewebsite.com.  My goal is to set the hyperlink for the project_name element to produce the URL.  The full url that I need to produce is http://www.somewebsite.com + /department_name/staff_member/project_name/project_name.html
or generic url + parameter-department_name/ + parameter-staff_member/ + element-project_name/ + element-project_name + .html:

Main Report

**Project_Name**
project_1
project_2

Sub report hyperlink should be:
http://www.somewebsite/department/staff_member/project_1/project_1.html
http://www.somewebsite/department/staff_member/project_2/project2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this:

="https://www.somewebsite/"&[department_name]&"/"&[staff_member]&"/"&[project_name]&"/"&[project_name]&".html"

The non Parameters are surrounded by "" like the usual string builders. The "&" connects the String with the Parameter.